# How to check for either of primary keys in a composite key to be (or not be) a null value?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say there's a table with composite key like `pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4`. My rules dictate that none of these pks should be null. So I tried writing the query somewhat like this:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where pk1 is null 
   or pk2 is null 
   or pk3 is null 
   or pk4 is null
```

But this feels like a clumsy, verbose and an unnecessarily lengthy way of doing things. There has to be a better way somewhat like:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where any(pk1, pk2, pk3, p4) is null
```

Although MySQL supports `any()`, this syntax doesn't seem to be accepted in snowflake. Moreover, I couldn't find any function that's very much similar to `any()` in snowflake.

Some pages online have suggested the use of coalesce function. But that is very different from what I need.

This has become more difficult as I'm dealing with a composite key that's a combination of more than 8 primary keys. I understand making such a lengthy composite key is not a good practise but it has already been implemented that way and I'm a tester trying to evaluate it with some python automation. Please let me know if there's a better way of handling this  in snowflake

Comment: How can you have null in a composite primary key?

Comment: Why not just add NOT NULL constraints to the columns in the table? Checking this after-the-fact is a mistake / bug / code-smell...

Comment: To ensure we're not misunderstanding something, you should ***always*** make a [mre] (including table definitions, dummy sample data, etc) at directed here; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 2):

[`ARRAY_CONTAINS()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains) uses [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from) comparison, so you can build an array out of the `pkN`'s and see if it contains a *`null`*. Each `pkN` field can be of different type[:](https://imgur.com/a/rUZzaue)

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(NULL,[pk1,pk2,pk3,p4]);
```

---

Similar to how [`IN ()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/in) returns *`null`* if it finds a *`null`* on [either side of the operator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/in#using-null) because it uses regular null-unsafe equality `=` instead of [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from) construct, you can self-compare the set of fields. If *any* of them is *`null`*, the whole thing will be nullified. Again, element types here don't have to match[:](https://imgur.com/a/X9JaoLz)

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (   (pk1, pk2, pk3, p4) 
       =  (pk1, pk2, pk3, p4)) IS NULL;
```

---

[`COALESCE()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce) you mentioned does inverse of this: above emulates `ANY() IS NULL`, below emulates [`ALL() IS NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/all-subqueries.html).

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE COALESCE(pk1, pk2, pk3, p4) IS NULL;
```

Similar to [`greatest()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/greatest) and [`least()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78084002/5298879), this requires fields to be of matching types.

Comment: How is that "less clumsy" than 4 IS NULL checks?

Comment: @MatBailie Well, the first one does 3 whole `not null` checks *fewer* than the 4 `not null` checks we started off with :) The second one does zero such `not null` checks. One-over-clunk advantage of both scales proportionally to how many fields OP was brave enough to squeeze in there. My understanding of OP's aim was to be able to list the fields as a nice clean list, without wrapping each individually in a check, the same way they would in `any()` - I think this achieves that. If *clumsy* is supposed to relate to performance, I agree the lengthy `is null`'s leave little room for optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

May not be any less clumsy than your original SQL, but this is an alternative using LIKE ANY. LIKE ANY does not give useful results for Null, so this remaps Null values to **?!**.

```sql
select *
from any_table
where '?!' like any(ifnull(c1,'?!'), ifnull(c2,'?!'), ifnull(c3,'?!'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`least`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/least) function which returns null if any argument is `null`. The data types must be compatible though.

```
where least(pk1, pk2, pk3, p4) is null
```

Comment: This answer seems the leanest and closest match to the ANY() function in MySQL. You taught me something new today.

Comment: I note that you have said the data types must match. But in my scenario, that's not the case. Is there an alternate in that case?

Comment: Then I am afraid you need to use is null or some syntactic mumbo jumbo.

Comment: @Zegarek I am entitled to my opinion. You however have started making things personal. Stop that.

Comment: @VishwasRVibhu Bulk null check using array containment, self-comparison using `=`/`in()` [all accept varying types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78083453/5298879). @Salman A, you're right. I pulled my comment on your use of *mumbo jumbo*, waiving my right to opinion on that.

Answer (score 1):

Another array based approach comes to mind. For brevity, I am using the number of columns on right hand side instead of `array_size([pk1,pk2 pk3,pk4])`. Sure it adds an extra step (I didn't like it at first) but realized it can come in handy if you need to check for variable number of non-null columns.

```
where array_size(array_compact([pk1,pk2 pk3,pk4])) = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A type agnostic variation to `least` can be concocted using `array_sort`

```
where array_sort([pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4], false)[0] is null;
```

That said, anything other than the verbose solution you have already have or the `array_contain` approach from Zegarek will start to approach the "mumbo jumbo" territory. That includes this answer as well